# How to print a part of the model using the same structure as a raft?

Tags: ultimaker-cura, pla, slicing

[image: 3D rendering of four models]

Using Cura or another slicer if needed, how could I print the part that needs bending using a structure similar to the one used for rafts.

In Cura, for reference they look like this:

[image: A Cura preview of an open raft]

[image: A Cura preview of a raft with crosshatch]

[image: A Cura preview of a horizontal raft]

[image: A Cura preview of a raft 90 degrees to the previous model]

I know this structure is probably good enough for the base of this object, even though other problems may arise later. So how can  I have something close to this structure in Cura for a part of the model?

Comment: Does "[Different infill in the same part](/q/6522/)" answer your question? You can e.g. use different infill or different shells, e.g. no shells or walls.